# Функция для вывода определенного элемента двумерного массива

Tags: c++

Код отображает введенный массив в виде таблицы.
Затем нужна функция которая будет просить ввести номер элемента двумерного массива, [i][j], а затем выводит необходимый элемент на экран. Я понимаю что `cout << setw(3) << matrix[i][j];` это и есть вывод, но помогите реализовать с введенными данными.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int M; 
    int N;
    cout << "Visota: "; cin >> M;
    cout << "Shirina: "; cin >> N;
    int i, j;
    int** matrix;

matrix = new int* [M];
for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    matrix[i] = new int[N];

for (i = 0; i < M; i++) 
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        cout << "Nomer " << "[" << i << "][" << j << "]  ";
        cin >> matrix[i][j];
    }

cout << endl;
cout << "Vid tablitsi";
cout <<endl;
for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        if (j % N == 0)
            cout << endl;
        cout << setw(3) << matrix[i][j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить

```
for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        if (j % N == 0)
            cout << endl;
        cout << setw(3) << matrix[i][j];
    }
}
```

на

```
for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        cout << setw(3) << matrix[i][j];
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Так вас устроит?

Только у вас точно не будет чисел больших, чем двузначные?..